# Warping path for print on curved canvas

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to create some artwork that will be printed on an curved object (an inflatable event tent). I'm having a hard time figuring out how to prepare the file.

The question is: How can I split an warp the pattern in such a way, it will look complete and undistorted when printed and put together again.

This is what the final object will look like (printable area is colored):

[image]

This is the template file I got:

[image]

This is the pattern/artwork I want to put on it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would model the object in 3D (measure it first or ask for a file in 3d that might be used to produce the inflatable on the first place) and UV map it, apply the texture and use the resulting exported map to print the design, it would be extreme difficult/ imprecise any other way. Good luck.

Comment: I agree - assuming that the model created (or downloaded from the supplier) correctly shows the tension curves of the fabric as in the initial picture in OP's post.
Were there no tension curves to be considered, if one plotted curves that remained perpendicular to each of the radial lines in the template and were contiguous, this should suffice for pattern matching, however most people lack this sort of graphic extrapolation skillset: Model, UV unwrap, 3D paint w/ grid would be best option.